# Passing a parameter into a lambda style callbcak

Tags: typescript, lambda

Hello I am trying to pass a parameter into a callback to a service that i have. I will change things up a bit here, but the idea will be the same.

I have a button that is called from the web ui.

```
<button (click)="doSomeWork(modal)">Button Name</button>
```

In the component I have this method.and have a service called `thisService`

```
private doSomeWork(modal){
     const message = 'Are you sure you want to do work, its coffee time!'
     this.thisService(()=>{
        // do some work here
        modal.close();
     },message);
}
```

Everything works from here except `modal.close()`, but this does work if it's outside of the callback so i can only assume that this is do to no reference to the modal. All of that said, there are not any errors that are thrown either.

If i do this i do get an error.

```
private doSomeWork(modal){
         const message = 'Are you sure you want to do work, its coffee time!'
         this.thisService((modal)=>{
            // do some work here
            modal.close();
         },message);
    }
```

The modal is no longer a modal but now an event so we cannot  pass in this way.

Comment: is `modal` `undefined` in the lambda?

Comment: no, it has all of its properties including the close() method

Comment: your modal variable have `NgbActiveModal` or `NgbModal` as type?

Comment: neither, we built it. it uses onInit.